# display category name instead id in mat table angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

Hello I use angular material mat table so to display my data from an api. I use another api so to handle the Categories.
I have two models,  **issues** and **categories**. For the time I display the **ID** of the **category**.
I need to display the corresponding **category** **name instead of its id**.

Any idea?

**My models**

```js
export class Issue {
  IssueID: string;
  IssueTitle: string;
  IssueContent: string;
  CategoryID: number;
}


export class IssueCategory {
  public CategoryID: number;
  public CategoryName: string;
}
```

**My html**

```html
...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="CategoryTitle">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Category</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.categoryID}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
...
```

**EDIT**

**My getAllIssues()**

```
CategoryArray: TicketCategory[] = [];

getAllIssues(): void {
this.httpClient.get<Ticket[]>(this.API_URL).subscribe(data => {
this.dataChange.next(data);      

  this.data.map(issue => ({

    category: this.CategoryArray.find(category => category.CategoryID === issue.CategoryID)
  }));
  }
 }
```

thank you!

Comment: I would create a combined type where you fill in the category object instead of the id and use that combined type for your table

Answer (score 2):

As the simplest approach you can use already combined data as the data source, for example:

```js
// my-component.ts

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  readonly categories: IssueCategory[] = [{
    CategoryID: 1,
    CategoryName: "First Category"
  }, {
    CategoryID: 2,
    CategoryName: "Second Category"
  }];

  readonly issues: Issue[] = [
    {IssueID: "first", IssueTitle: "First Issue", IssueContent: "first issue content", CategoryID: 1},
    {IssueID: "second", IssueTitle: "Second Issue", IssueContent: "second issue content", CategoryID: 2}
  ];

  readonly dataSource = this.issues.map(issue => ({
    title: issue.IssueTitle,
    content: issue.IssueContent,
    category: this.categories.find(category => category.CategoryID === issue.CategoryID)
  }));
}
```

Or you can create a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) which transforms a category id to the name. In this case keep in mind that you should include your pipe in the declarations array of an module.

```js
// category-by-id.pipe.ts

@Pipe({
  name: 'categoryById'
})
export class CategoryByIdPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categoryId: number, categories: IssueCategory[]): string {
    const category = categories.find(category => category.CategoryID === categoryId);
    return category ? category.CategoryName : "";
  };
}
```

```html
<!-- my-component.html -->

...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CategoryID | categoryById:categories}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
...
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rduaqx?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.ts) with both examples. Hope it helps you.

---

[Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rduaqx-zu9ii6?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.ts) another example which uses `MatTableDataSource`

Comment: thank you for your reply @Valerin. I try to fit your code from the first approach. I already have a datasource from where I fill my mat-table from api. How can I add the second one?

Comment: @touinta Could you add more details about the problem? Why not replace the first data-source be the updated one?

Comment: I need my initial datasource because in there I do a lot of work as filtering, sorting etc...May I try to add your code to that?....its hard but I will give a try....

Comment: @touinta Ok, let me know if you'll have some troubles.

Comment: I update my question. I add my service function in which I add some of your code. How can through this call the category name in my component.html? Is that possible? thank you

Comment: @touinta I've added another example to the answer which uses `MatTableDataSource`. Hope it helps you.